# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix with admob ad

Tags: android

I have a working layout which look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, xxx"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

now i want to remove the LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9000079580883391/8483250253"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 4FBD7E211FFFF7D7"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

then i'm facing the error. I know I need to add the `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` but I dont know where

Comment: add to the root view in the layout

Comment: So i need to add it in a other file? then the error will be still there in eclipse

Comment: you must add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" lines

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` add both of these to your Adview

Comment: wow even googles sample code doesn't even have those xmlns attributes. good job!

Answer (score 3):

Use both

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads



xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.packagename
```

like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:id="@+id/adMob"
                           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                           ads:adUnitId="YOUR AdMob publisher ID"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```